# ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError on Angular 8 and method called on ngOnInit

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I'm facing some common issue on Angular template, I have this general template for all my pages and inside of it I have a *ngIf with a spinner inside and another one with my router-outlet.

The interceptor controlls the behavior and visibility of the spinner, so with that comes the error, in a specific component I subscribe on a http method on a ngOnInit and the result of that is the error.

This error just happen if I call some method on lifecycle methods.
I already tried some workarounds like envolve the setSpinnerState with setTimeout and tried to use other lifecycle hooks(AfterViewInit,  AfterContentInit...).

The interceptor

```
export class InterceptorService implements HttpInterceptor {

  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): import('rxjs').Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    this.layoutService.setSpinnerState(true);
    return next.handle(this.handlerRequest(req)).pipe(
      delay(3000),
      finalize(() => {
        this.layoutService.setSpinnerState(false);
      })
    );
  }

  constructor(private authService: AuthService, private layoutService: LayoutService) { }

  private handlerRequest(req: HttpRequest<any>) {
    let request;
    if (this.authService.isLoggedIn() && !req.url.includes('/assets/i18n/')) {
      request = req.clone({
        url: environment.api.invokeUrl + req.url,
        headers: req.headers.append('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + this.authService.getAcessToken())
      });
    } else if (req.url.includes('/assets/i18n/')) {
      request = req.clone();
    } else {
      request = req.clone({
        url: environment.api.invokeUrl + req.url
      });
    }
    return request;
  }

}
```

Layout Service:

```
export class LayoutService {

  private isSpinner: boolean = true;

  constructor() { }

  public setSpinnerState(state: boolean): void {
    this.isSpinner = state;
  }

  public getSpinnerState():boolean{
    return this.isSpinner;
  }


}
```

The general template(LayoutComponent)

```
<div class="page-wrapper fixed-nav-layout">
    <app-header (toggleEvent)="receiveToggle($event)"></app-header>
    <!--Page Body Start-->
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="page-body-wrapper sidebar-icon" [class.sidebar-close]="toggle">
            <app-sidebar class="page-sidebar page-sidebar-open"></app-sidebar>
            <div class="page-body p-t-10">
                <app-breadcrumb></app-breadcrumb>
                <router-outlet  *ngIf="!layoutService.getSpinnerState()"></router-outlet>
                <div class="loader-box d-flex justify-content-center align-self-center" *ngIf="layoutService.getSpinnerState()" async>
                    <div class="loader">
                        <div class="line bg-default"></div>
                        <div class="line bg-default"></div>
                        <div class="line bg-default"></div>
                        <div class="line bg-default"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!--Page Body End-->
    </div>
```

The component with the subscribe method

```
export class EditProfileComponent implements OnInit {

  public userProfile = new UserProfile();

  constructor(private userService: UserService) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getUser();
  }

  public getUser() {
    // debugger
    this.userService.getUser().subscribe(data => {
      this.userProfile = Amazon.feedUser(data);
    }, err => {
      return new ErrorHandler().show(err.message);
    });
  }
}
```

And the error stack

```
ERROR Error: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'ngIf: true'. Current value: 'ngIf: false'.
    at viewDebugError (core.js:28792)
    at expressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError (core.js:28769)
    at checkBindingNoChanges (core.js:29757)
    at checkNoChangesNodeInline (core.js:44442)
    at checkNoChangesNode (core.js:44415)
    at debugCheckNoChangesNode (core.js:45376)
    at debugCheckDirectivesFn (core.js:45273)
    at Object.eval [as updateDirectives] (LayoutsComponent.html:10)
    at Object.debugUpdateDirectives [as updateDirectives] (core.js:45258)
    at checkNoChangesView (core.js:44248)
```

At last I tried ChangeDetectorRef on LayoutComponent, but error doesn't changed.

```
export class LayoutsComponent implements OnChanges {

  public toggle;
  openToggle: boolean;

  constructor(public navService: NavService, public layoutService: LayoutService, private cd: ChangeDetectorRef) {
    if (this.navService.openToggle === true) {
      this.openToggle = !this.openToggle;
      this.toggle = this.openToggle;
    }
  }

  ngOnChanges(): void {
    this.cd.detectChanges();
  }

  receiveToggle($event) {
    this.openToggle = $event;
    this.toggle = this.openToggle;
  }

}
```

The error reproduced on stackblitz:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xyulo9

Comment: You question is unclear with layoutService missing and non-relevant code. Please reproduce a [mvce](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for example on stackblitz - you can replace http calls by `of(httpData).pipe(delay(100))`. I've produced a [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-so58276430-demo-change-detection-issue) but I can't be sure how close to your example this is.

Comment: @AndrewAllen My LayoutService just set the spinner state to true or false.But I edit my question with the service. I had tried your solution, but the error still the same.
Later I'll try to reproduce the error on stackblitz.

Comment: is `EditProfileComponent` rendered via `router-outlet`? If so, this should be enough information to reproduce error and offer a few ideas on solutions

Comment: @AndewAllen https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xyulo9

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### [Original Stackblitz*](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-so58276430-original-plus-logs)

*ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError* is a development check to ensure bindings update in a manner Angular expects. The order of change detection when it run is as follows:

1. OnInit, DoCheck, OnChanges
2. Renders
3. Change detection runs on child views
4. AfterViewChecked, AfterViewInit

A final development check makes sure there are no changes after having been checked (else all the children would need to be updated).

The problem is that `layoutService.getSpinnerState()` is changed by the child after the parent has determined and "rendered" this.

### [Stackblitz - A Solution](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-so58276430-attempt-solution)

The problem you have boils down to

1. Where should you call `getUser()`?

   > For the sake of simplicity I've called this in *AppComponent*.
   >
   > If you call this in *EditProfileComponent OnInit* this will trigger an infinite loop.
   >
   > spinner is false, Parent renders Child, Child calls *getUser()*, spinner set to true, Parent removes Child and with the http response we repeat.
2. How to pass data to `EditProfileComponent`?

   > For the sake of simplicity I've created a *PassDataService* to hold the data and then pass this along on *EditProfileComponent OnInit*.

Alternatives include using a guard or resolver or allowing `EditProfileComponent` to render but having the spinner overlay this until the http response.

### Unidirectional Data Flow

AppComponent → calls getUser() with data saved in service → sets spinnerState true → renders spinner

On recieving data:

interceptor → sets spinnerState false → renders router-outlet → renders EditProfileComponent → data passed from service

---

<sub>*This is the same as the original stackblitz but with logging added to give an idea of change detection and the lifecycle hooks as well as putting the template inside the ts file for easier analysis.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

```
finalize(() => {
  this.layoutService.setSpinnerState(false);
})
```

Seems the spinner state is being set after the value is checked. Inject `NgZone` into your `InterceptorService` and wrap `this.layoutService.setSpinnerState` within ngZone. This way angular will be aware of the change and no longer complain about it changing.

```
this.ngZone.run(() => {
  this.layoutService.setSpinnerState(false);
});
```

Comment: So Noremac, I tried your solution, but the interceptor don't accept functions with void return and throws the error:
```
Argument of type 'void' is not assignable to parameter of type 'OperatorFunction<unknown, HttpEvent<any>>'
```
And I tried to wrap with finalize, but doen't work either. 
````